# String space in Keys Selenium Driver

Tags: python, selenium

**Hi I have a problem with selenium spaces in keys. Example:**

```
search = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search.send_keys("Juan Dela Cruz") **if I put spaces I got no return** 
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

search = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search.send_keys("JuanDelaCruz") **but if I removed the spaces it works** 
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

**Please help me with this error. Thanks**

Comment: There is no problem in your code. Both the codes are running as expected in my laptop. Try adding explicit wait in your code and see the 1st one will fetch result. Let us know if you are facing any specific error.

Comment: I tried         main = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "quote"))
            ) but still not working

Comment: What error it is showing? Where it stuck?

Comment: There is no error showing, but it doesn't return any results

Comment: but when I removed the spaces, I got results from selenium.

Comment: Please help me with this weird error. hehehe

Comment: hi still there? Please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Restart your laptop/computer and then try again.. Sometimes the computer runs slow and creates weird problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` instead of `search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`

Comment: the Enter works but the spaces is causing the weird behaviour.

Comment: Hi still there?

Comment: yes, but I don't have any idea what it can be. It worked for me perfectly with sending Enter keys.